# Get contents of a div infront of another div it contain

Tags: php, jquery

When `see more button` is clicked, second passage shows but there is a gap in between them as per shown in the screenshot. I want the second passages to continue with first one

[image]

```js
function ClickParent(ClickElem,ElemFind)
    {   
        $("."+ClickElem).click(function() {
            var GetGrp  =   $(this).parents(".group");
            GetGrp.find("."+ElemFind).fadeToggle();
        }); 
    }

// Find one level
ClickParent('name','moreinfo');
// Find another level
ClickParent('moreinfo','evenmore');
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <a href="#" class="name" style="color:black;">How are you?</a>
    <div class="moreinfo" style="display: none;">
        Fine
    </div>
    <div class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
        Even more stuff.
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get result from `How are you?`? `Fine` answer should be next to the question with no space.

Comment: You might want to explain a bit more? What should be clicked, what should be displayed? I don't understand...

Comment: A user will select from two answers `Fine` and `Even more stuff.`? Selecting an answer can be done by clicking the `div`? If `Fine` was selected, you want it to go in-front OR next to the question? Covering the question? Is that right?

Comment: You could simply make as jquery onclick, display: block. Or another way is,   $('.name').click(function(){
        $('.moreinfo').toggle();
   });

Comment: onclick of question answer should be infront of question instead of new line

Comment: In front? Meaning covering the question? Or directly next to the question? And it would be much easier if you could provide a screen shot. And better explanation.

Comment: have a look at [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) if you want to move "fine" in front of "how are you"

Comment: i added screen shot. i want on click of see more button second passge is showing but there is gap between them how to show second passage continue to first one one so it show as one passges

Comment: how to show answer directly next to the question.?

Comment: so i get idea how to work with my project.?

Comment: @LoganWayne  answer next to question.

Answer (score 0):

I get now what you want for your project. You wanted a "Read more" function for your articles.

Using `<div></div>` to hide your continued text/string causes a new line. You can just replace it with `<font></font>`.

```
<!-- FIRST ARTICLE -->
<div class="group">
  <a href="#" class="name" style="color:black;">This is the first article that would </a>
  <font class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
    show more information about this first article.
  </font>
  <div class="moreinfo">
    See more
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND ARTICLE -->
<div class="group">
  <a href="#" class="name" style="color:black;">This is the second article that would </a>
  <font class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
    show more information about this second article.
  </font>
  <div class="moreinfo">
    See more
  </div>
</div>
```

Then let us create a script that when "See more" is clicked, it will hide this "See more" and would show the content inside `<font></font>`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".moreinfo").click(function(){ /* WHEN SEE MORE IS CLICKED */
    var elem = $(this);
    $(this).fadeOut(200).hide(); /* HIDE THE CLICKED SEE MORE */
    elem.closest("div.group").find('font.evenmore').fadeIn(200).show(); /* SHOW THE CONTENT OF THE CLOSEST FONT */
  });

});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6bz1u4b/). But if you want to hide the shown details, we can add a "Show Less". Check this second [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6bz1u4b/2/).